# Listing all uninstalled apps on android device

Tags: android, security, mobile

I think my phone got compromised. I want to know the list of android apps installed my device so far including uninstalled one.

Comment: Compromised? doubtful. What phone do you have? Usually its Settings> Application Manager... Or if you log into your google account and go into your google play store, click the hamburger menu and click on my apps and  games...or something like that. That will display it too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Also, by definition, uninstalled apps would not show up in a list of installed apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare wouldn't be possible to get Google API?

Comment: I think operating system keep track of apps. Otherwise one can never know what apps were installed on the device which is very crucial information in evaluating aftermath.